# Running Apache on port 80

Tags: apache, http

I just installed xampp win32 1.7.4 in my windows 7 computer.

When I try to open the Apache server, it says that port 80 is busy and as a result I can't run Apache server  in my computer.

How should I overcome from this?

Answer (score 1):

That means another process is already listening on port 80. To find out which process, open command prompt in administrator mode and run:

```
netstat -abn
```

which should tell you what process is listening on each port. You should be able to then stop this process. It could also be a service in which case you can disable the service from Control Panel.